# How to restrict table row height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've  created TABLE mentioned below:

```
<html>    
<body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
        <colgroup>
            <col span="1" style="width:5%">
                <col span="1" style="width:70%">
                    <col span="1" style="width:25%">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 100px;">Sample Text 1</div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="5">
                <section class="loginform">
                    <fieldset style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px;">
                        <legend>Template</legend>
                        <ul style="padding: 10px;">
                            <li>one</li>
                            <li>Two</li>
                            <li>Three</li>
                            <li>Four</li>
                            <li>Five</li>
                        </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </section>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>val</td>
            <td>
                <div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 80px;">1 Only</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bal</td>
            <td>
                <div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 80px;">2 only</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nal</td>
            <td>
                <div style="width:100%; color:black; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 80px;">Both 1 and 2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dul</td>
            <td>
                <div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 80px;">Neither 1 nor 2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>    
</html>
```

In this table; I want to ensure that height of Template (section on right hand side) ; is always equal to height of five ROWS of the table. If data inside template is more, it should come with scroll-bar. But in no case it should go beyond height of five rows of the table. Can you please suggest ?

Comment: use __`max-height`__ in __css__

Comment: I tried this for the TD with rowspan= 5 ; but somehow it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set a fixed height.

Check out this one :-

http://jsfiddle.net/8tFnG/

```
<fieldset style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px;height: 450px; border: solid 1px red;">
```

Comment: Thanks Anup; How to add scroll bar ; if there are more elements in the Template Section?

Comment: Somehow... it's giving some issue on Firefox... on other browsers it's working fine...

Answer (score 1):

If you know the height of the five rows on the left, you could "restrict" the height of your "Template" fieldset with a simple css rule: `max-height: 400px; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;` where 400px is the height of the five rows in the table; overflow is hidden and overflow on y-axis is set to scroll. Try it out:

```
.loginform fieldset{
    height: 400px;
    max-height: 400px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Another option is to use JavaScript. You could find out the height of the table containing the five rows, and then adjusting the height of the "Template" fieldset on page load.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You; it's working perfectly; I tried this after Anup's so accepted his answer. Thanks for your understanding in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css:**

```
<style>
    fieldset{ height: 450px;overflow-y:hidden;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

add position:fixed to the element